# ISPconfig url shows default Apache content

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, php, http, control-panel

I seen this problem on few users but I didn't find a solution.
I run Centos 7 and installed ISPconfig by downloading, then running

`php install.php`

It configured some things like ssl, apache, etc, but some steps failed (like some apache ssl for example) and I had to restart the `php install.php` a few times in order to install missing dependencies.

I set ISPconfig on `port 81` and set it to use ssl url.

**Problem:** When opening `https://192.168.1.x:81` I get default apache content `from /var/www/html` and not the ISPconfig interface from `/var/www/ispconfig/`

Others mentioned that there might be a vhost conflict, but I don't think so, because I searched for `:81` inside `/etc/httpd/` folder and I could only find it inside one file: `/etc/httpd/conf/sites-available/ispconfig.vhost`, if I change the port there to something like `83`, then it starts responding on new port and stops responding on old `81`, this makes me think there are no multiple vhosts defined /conflicts.

What can I try ?

```
######################################################
# This virtual host contains the configuration
# for the ISPConfig controlpanel
######################################################

Listen 81
NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost _default_:81>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  <Directory /var/www/ispconfig/>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
  </Directory>
  <Directory /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web/>
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
  </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ispconfig/
    SuexecUserGroup ispconfig ispconfig
    <Directory /var/www/ispconfig/>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +ExecCGI
      AllowOverride AuthConfig Indexes Limit Options FileInfo
      <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler fcgid-script
      </FilesMatch>
      FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/ispconfig/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            Require all granted
          </Directory>
    IPCCommTimeout  7200
    MaxRequestLen 15728640
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web/
    AssignUserId ispconfig ispconfig
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    <Directory /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web>
      # php_admin_value open_basedir "/usr/local/ispconfig/interface:/usr/share:/tmp"
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
            php_value magic_quotes_gpc        0
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>

  # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature Off

  <IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine Off
  </IfModule>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine On
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv3
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.key
  #SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.bundle

  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
        RequestHeader unset Proxy early
  </IfModule>

    SSLUseStapling On
  SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
  SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors Off
  </VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/php-cgi-scripts>
  AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
  </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts>
  AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **rakib_buet** at webhostingtalk forum, I fixed it by ...

```
yum install mod_fcgid
service httpd restart
```

Looks like mod_fcgid was not installed and the apache config files for ispconfig were setting instructions based on it `<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>...</IfModule>`, maybe it can be fixed with better ISPconfig templates for these files.